# Чтение xml-файла

Tags: xml, delphi

Имеется следующий xml-файл:

```
Base xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" BaseName="MyTestbase2">
Tables Count="3">
Table TableName="Abonents">
Column DataType="Integer">
iID
/Column>
Column DataType="Character" ValueSize="50">
cName
/Column>
Column DataType="Character" ValueSize="300">
cAddress
/Column>
Column DataType="Date">
dBornDate
/Column>
Column DataType="Blob" ValueSize="1000">
bPhoto
/Column>
/Table>
```

Как прочитать данные `DataType`, `ValueSize` и имя реквизита (например `cName`) в Delphi, используя компонент `XMLDocument`?

Comment: что никто не знает как это сделать?

Comment: Почитайте вот эту статью: [Парсинг XML на Delphi](http://parsing-and-i.blogspot.ru/2008/08/xml-delphi.html). Думаю, она вам поможет.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, я ее смотрел уже... Вопрос такой, как можно позиционировать на определенном элементе (например на Table), если их несколько и они содержат вложенные поля?

Comment: XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Nodes[i].Text - укажите только i правильно.

Answer (score 2):

На определенном элементе нельзя позиционироваться :) Вам надо знать структуру XML-файла.

```
procedure Parse(filename: string); 
var 
 doc: IXMLDocument;
 node, table, field: IXMLNode;
 tables, fields: IXMLNodeList; 
 i, tablescount, j: integer;
 tmpvalue: string;
begin 
 doc := TXMLDocument.Create(filename);
 doc.LoadFromFile('');
 node := doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode('Tables'); 
 tablescount := node.Attributes['Count']; 
 tables := node.ChildNodes;
 for i := 0 to tablescount - 1 do 
   begin 
     table := tables[i]; 
     tmpvalue := table.Attributes['TableName'];
     fields := table.ChildNodes; 
     for j := 0 to fields.Count - 1 do 
       begin 
         field := fields[j];
         tmpvalue := fields.ChildValues[j]; //имя поля 
         tmpvalue := field.Attributes['DataType']; //тип поля 
         tmpvalue := field.Attributes['ValueSize']; //размер поля
       end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: doc := TXMLDocument.Create(filename);
и
tmpvalue := fields.ChildValues[j];
проблемные строчки показывает ошибку.

Comment: чего ж неизвестные, известные. uses XMLIntf и F1 вам в помощь. :) Кроме того, парсер сайта сьел теги и процедура написана в предположении, что элементы Table содержатся в Tables. Если нет, то придется проходить по всем детям коренного элемента, проверять их имя и действовать в зависимости от этого.

Comment: а какую ошибку показывает?

Comment: первая ошибка: [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(36): E2018 Record, object or class type required

вторая ошибка:[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(49): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ChildValues'

Comment: первой ошибки у меня нет (Д7), а вторая таки есть. Не fields.ChildValues[j], а table.ChildValues[j].